# SOLR Cores not loading

Tags: solr

Disclaimer - I know nothing about SOLR.  We have been asked by someone to look into why their SOLR instance isn't working correctly.  Hoping someone could help me troubleshoot their issue.

They are running SOLR 9.1.0 and are finding a number of cores are not loading.  The error they are getting is "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException".  To "fix" this, they restart the SOLR service and it will load the core.

I have checked the logs and this is the error within:

```
(coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1) [] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [Test]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [Test]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:1009) ~[?:?]
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [Test]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1613) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:980) ~[?:?]
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:1203) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:1047) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1590) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:980) ~[?:?]
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:229) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1522) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1317) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.obtainLock(FilterDirectory.java:106) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.isWriterLocked(SolrCore.java:848) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:869) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:1122) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:1047) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1590) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$12(CoreContainer.java:980) ~[?:?]
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
```

I have checked permissions but other than that, i am out of ideas.

Comment: Are you running multiple cores from the same directory? Either from a network share, or multiple servers or multiple cores from the same underlying config directory. The error stems from a lock being aquired on a file, then someone else trying to lock the same file at the same time - i.e. two servers / cores / etc. trying to get exclusive access to the resources. There's different locking methods available in Solr, but generally you should not have to tweak those (and that can be dangerous if you don't know exactly why and what you're doing).

Comment: There are 8 cores which are being loaded.  They all live in the same directory Solr\Server\Solr.  There is only one SOLR server in this environment.

Comment: Verify that two cores aren't using the same underlying core directory (under the third level solr path or wherever your cores are stored). Also, if Solr crashed earlier (for example from a full disk), there might be a lock file lingering. If there is no Solr instance running, make sure there aren't any lock files present on the disk that blocks Solr from locking the directory. The file would generally be named `write.lock` and present in the `data` directory for the core.

Comment: I can't see any locks.  Once all the cores are running it's stable. However, if we need to reboot the server then only some of the cores start and the others encounter the errors above.  We then go through a process of restarting the SOLR service until all cores are loaded.  All cores are using a different folder for example Solr\server\Test1 & Solr\server\Test2.  With each directory i have a Conf & Data folders with a core.properties.

Comment: Are you using NFS or another network file system? "Note that because this LockFactory relies on java.nio.* APIs for locking, any problems with those APIs will cause locking to fail. Specifically, on certain NFS environments the java.nio.* locks will fail (the lock can incorrectly be double acquired) whereas SimpleFSLockFactory worked perfectly in those same environments. For NFS based access to an index, it's recommended that you try SimpleFSLockFactory first and work around the one limitation that a lock file could be left when the JVM exits abnormally."